# Passing Bourne Shell variable into cut command

Tags: shell, unix, variables, scripting, sh

I am trying to do the following.

```
foo="foo:foo1"
cc= `$foo | cut -f2 -d:`
```

I understand why this would not work but I am at a loss as to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo="foo:foo1"
cc=`echo $foo | cut -f2 -d:`
```

There are 2 changes to make:

- You need to echo the value of shell
  variable foo and then cut it.
- You must not have white spaces around `=`
  when assigning a value to a shell
  variable.

Answer (score 0):

in bourne, you can use set. No external command needed.

```
$ foo="foo:foo1"
$ IFS=":"
$ set -- $foo
$ echo $2
foo1
```